# Custom description method not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Trying to write a custom description method for my NSManagedObject subclass and it instead of print that data in self.myvarname it prints out "Myvarname"  or printing self.userCount it prints "UserCount"?

Followed this example: http://brandontreb.com/objective-c-tutorial-helpful-debugging-by-overriding-the-description-method/

Also, why in the xcode console when I type "po myroominstance.name" or "po myroominstance.usage"  does it say no property found (given the class below)?

Here is my class:

```
.h
===================
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Rooms : NSManagedObject
{
  NSString *name;
  NSNumber *capacity;
  NSString *descr;
  NSString *usage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * capacity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * descr;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * usage;

@end


.M
==================
#import "Rooms.h"

@implementation Rooms

@dynamic name;
@dynamic capacity;
@dynamic descr;
@dynamic usage;

-(NSString *) description 
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID: %@ Name: %@ Website: %n",
        usage  ,descr,name];
}

@end
```

UPDATE 1:=========================================================

```
====== My break point is on this line ==========
Room *myRoom = [Room findFirst];
NSLog(@"The room name is %@", myRoom.name);
================================================
```

If I break at the NSlog line above, which by the way prints out "The room name is Name" and then type, in the console, "po myRoom.name" I get "Name".  If I type "po myRoom.descr" I get "Descr".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither of the others get the formatting quite correct, but they're barking up the wrong tree, anyway. You seem to have copied the `-description` method from the tutorial you linked to and not adjusted it to match your class.

You could implement it like so:

```
- (NSString*) description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@ %p> name %@, capacity %@, descr %@, usage %@", [self class], self, name, capacity, descr, usage];
}
```

(There's no need to invoke `-intValue` on `capacity` and then use the "%d" formatting specifier.)

However, that doesn't explain why you're not getting the results you expect during a debugging session or when asking for the description of one of your instances.  Please edit your question and add the specifics of how you're asking for the description and what *exactly* you're getting. For example, are you logging your instances in code? If so, show the logging statements and the output. Are you using `po` in the debugger? If so, show the actual command and the output.

Comment: See my changes above per your request.

Comment: OK, so what's the problem? You aren't attempting to print the `myRoom` object itself, so we wouldn't expect the `-description` method to be used. You're just printing the specific properties of `myRoom`. I suspect it's showing you exactly what those properties are. That is, I assume the `name` property of `myRoom` really is "Name" and the `descr` property really is "Descr". What were you expecting?